# Add children to React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add a child to a React component. `this.props.children` seems to be read-only so can't mutate it directly.

Let's say I have

```
var myComponent = <MyComponent someProp="foo"><h1>heading</h1><h2>another heading</h2></MyComponent>
```

and I'd like to add `<p>some text</p>` as a third child to it.

I'd like to accomplish this:

```
var newChild = <p>some text</p>
myComponent.props.children.add(newChild)
```

so that the result would be

```
<MyComponent someProp="foo"><h1>heading</h1><h2>another heading</h2><p>some text</p></MyComponent>
```

(obviously the add function doesn't exist but the question is what to do instead)

Comment: You should never modify the contents of a component's render from outside the component. You should either just change the children in a parent component's render function, or have MyComponent render children based on props, as in <MyComponent rows={ [{ heading: 'heading' }] } etc

Comment: when do u want to add the third element?

Answer (score 2):

The `children` prop represents the content inserted between the tags of a JSX element (see [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)), and is not supposed to be modified directly. In fact, attempting to perform modifications on any content inside of `this.props` is usually unthinkable.

To address your particular problem, you seem to wish to define what children are added to a component, as in something like this:

```
// parent component's render method
render() {
  const elements = ...; //build up an array of elements
  return (<MyComponent someProp="foo">
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <h2>another heading</h2>
    {elements}
  </MyComponent>)
}
```

The root element of type `MyComponent` would then know how to use these children for a proper render, which are made available in `this.props.children`. If this component needs to actively trigger the inclusion of text, then you could either include a text change callback as a prop to `MyComponent`, or just use component state (thus refraining from using the children for that paragraph at all).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll have to look into the different solutions you offered. I'd like to clarify my question a bit. What I'm actually trying to do is something like this:
http://pastebin.com/31nuQC7w

Result for example:
`<MyComponent>
  <MySubComponent />
  <MySubComponent />
  <MySubComponent />
</MyComponent>
<MyComponent>
  <MySubComponent />
</MyComponent>`

Comment: @J.Doe Although I am still not sure of what you intend to do, I have just updated my question based on your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a state that has all the children to the component.

Try adding to the state instead of the props, and in render write:

```
render() {
return ({<div>this.state.children.map((child) => {return <child as jsx>;}}</div>);
```